# Images disappearing from Vaadin grid in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm creating a monitoring application based on Vaadin, where I'm using the Grid component to show a row for each of the network nodes that I am monitoring. Each row shows the node name, status text and a status image corresponding to if the node is "OK", "Warning" or "Error".

To show the status image, I'm using a componentColumn, which is filled with an Image object corresponding to the node status. A backend system will retrieve updated statuses from the nodes, and if the status has changed a refresh on the Grid DataProvider for that node will update the text and image.

My problem is that when viewing the application in Chrome, the images are not shown. When refreshing it will only paint a couple of the pictures, and after a while when the background push mechanism has updated the images, all have disappeared. This does not seem to happen with Firefox.

The Grid component:

```
grid.addComponentColumn(node -> {
if(node.isError()) {
    return new Image(null,new ClassResource("/img/error.png"));
}
else if(node.isWarning()) {
    return new Image(null,new ClassResource("/img/warning.png"));
}
else{
    return new Image(null,new ClassResource("/img/ok.png"));
}
})
```

When refreshing a node:

```
dataProvider.refreshItem(node);
```

In network inspector for Firefox, we occasionally get:

```
com.vaadin.client.ui.AbstractComponentConnector
SEVERE: Widget is still attached to the DOM after the connector (ImageConnector (11363)) has been unregistered. Widget was removed.
```

But the images remain visible. In Chrome we occasionally get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()http://192.168.28.12:8090/vaadinServlet/APP/connector/3/55643/source/ok.png
```

**Tried switching to using ImageRenderer instead**:

```
grid.addColumn(
                node -> getThemeResource(node.isError(),node.isWarning()),
                new ImageRenderer<>()
        );
```

getThemeResource:

```
private ThemeResource getThemeResource(boolean isError, boolean isWarning) {
    if(isError) {
        return new ThemeResource("img/error.png"));
    }
    else if(isWarning) {
        return new ThemeResource("img/warning.png"));
    }
    else
        return new ThemeResource("img/ok.png"));
    }
}
```

Since I am using Spring Boot with Vaadin and my theme is the standard Valo theme, I put the images at

Myapp/src/main/resource/VAADIN/themes/valo/img

I don't get any errors when running, but the pictures do not show up in my Grid. However, in the Chrome browser network monitor I can see that the image is downloaded from http://localhost:8090/VAADIN/themes/valo/img/ok.png

Comment: Any differences between the network inspectors in Chrome vs Firefox?

Comment: Updated the question with information from network inspector in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Adding Images via ComponentColumn to Grid is a bit suboptimal, I would recommend to use ImageRenderer https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.3/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/renderers/ImageRenderer.html instead.

Comment: Have tried switching to ImageRenderer but have not been able to get the images visible in the grid. Please see updated question.